# dynamic binding between processes

Tags: c#, reflection, process, ipc, inter-process-communicat

I'm trying to create a system that will be very modular. with the idea in mind that no module should really know about any other module (each running in it's own process).

There will be another program that will open, and will be able to tell what these modules will send and receive(this I largely have covered).

the issue I'm having at the moment, is there a way for me to be able to interrogate the application inside another process, or app domain? and in so doing late bind these modules together.

EG:
A module that can broadcast 'X' at runtime will be liked to a module that can accept 'X'.

This may be quite vague, and if so please ask me to clarify on anything I have not covered.

Right now, I Just need to know if it is possible to interrogate a process, and if so how? I Am fairly new to this but my initial research hasn't taken me to far.

Answer (score 0):

I modeled a system like this recently for a personal home automation system. Basically, I'd want to be able to have certain sensors (microphones, cameras, etc.) broadcast what they have, and have other computers or programs get that information whenever they need it, without knowing exactly who is going to be getting the data at compile time.

If this sounds like what you're looking for, I'd look into a Pub-Sub style architecture.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern

You're not really interrogating the process in this kind of architecture, but I think you get a similar result. Basically, you'll have one main pub-sub server.

[image]

In the Diagram above, Clients 2 and 3 "subscribe" to receive a specific kind of message. The server knows who is subscribed to what, so that when Client 1 sends that message, the server knows it needs to route it to the correct clients.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: After re-reading your question, I feel that you may have already gotten this far. Maybe all you need is something like

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102(v=vs.110).aspx

Pipes allow you to pass some information between processes. You'll have to serialize and de-serialize the data across the pipe, but this (coupled with a pub-sub architecture) should give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks, funny enough this is for a home system as well. I'm looking to be able to create the modules without needing to know where the server, or other modules will be, But I'll look into this. Thank you

Comment: With this architecture, any one module wouldn't need to know anything at all about any other module. It would only need to know about what "kind" of data it wants to receive. Each module would have to know about the server though, as the client modules would need to tell the server that they care about a certain kind (or kinds) of data.

Comment: Thanks, I may well end up going down this path